# can i execute more than one action in the same time with react redux

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-thunk

i'm  new in react-redux , Now im  trying to execute two different action in componentDidMount lifecycle but the problem is that redux override the result of the first action and i get only the second result
i wanna now how i can use one dispatch to execute more than one action in react-redux .
and if i can execute more than one action with react-reduw using react-thunk as a midelaware

```
 componentDidMount() {

  
this.props.getmessagesss(Cookies.get("_id"))

  }[image of probleme][1]

/* action code */ 
export const getmessagesss = (id) => { return  async (dispatch) => {
    let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(Axios.get(URL+"app/allannonce"))
     })
      let promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       resolve(Axios.get(URL + `app/getmessage/${id}`))
     }); 
     await  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(values => {
          const dat1 = values[0].data;
          const dat2 =  values[1].data;
          dispatch(getallanonces(dat1))
          dispatch(dispatchmessages(dat2))
         
     
       })
export const getallanonces = payload => ({
    type :GETALLANNONCE,
    payload
})
export const dispatchmessages = paylod => ({
    type : GETTALLMESSAGE,
    paylod
})
/* reducer code  */ 

const message = ""
export const boitemessage = (state = message , action) => {
if (action.type==GETTALLMESSAGE)

return   action.paylod
else
return state
}
const Ann = ""
export const Annonce = (state = Ann , action) => 
{
    switch(action.type){
        case (Annoce.GETALLANNONCE) :
            return action.payload
 
            
        case(Annoce.GETONEANNONCE):
        return    [action.payload]
        
    
        default:
        return []
    
        }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tx41.png
```

Comment: Please reformat your code, as this is not really readable

Comment: What is the problem? What actions are dispatched (see redux dev tools)? Do they have the correct payload? Do they change the state correctly? If not then provide the information and expected versus actual behavior.